# Modelica example "Interaction1" not working as expected

Tags: openmodelica

I encountered the following issue when simulating the example "Interaction1" from Modelica library ("Modelica.Blocks.Examples.Interaction1") in OpenModelica: This examples contains a block "Modelica.Blocks.Interaction.Show.RealValue", thus I was expecting that the number in the respective block (in Diagram Window) would update when changing the time slider position after simulation (according to its description: "Show Real value from numberPort or from number input field in diagram layer dynamically"). However, the value stays "0.0", irrespective of the current time.

Does anybody know what might be the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [nightly-builds](https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/windows/nightly-builds/), we have implemented more of the DynamicSelect.

[image]